# Chromium debugger highlight is one line off

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

I am executing JS script within the CEF project via CEFSharp's ExecuteScriptAsync. The code is executing correctly. I have embedded a "debugger" statement into my JS code. The devtools is manually started and then the script is executed. The debugger stops the script, but the script is stopped with the highlight on the line before the debugger statement. The sources tab appears with the code loaded;

```
<script>
function runScript() {
    debugger;
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        print(i);
    }                
}; 
runScript();
</script>
```

So in the case above the statement

```
function runScript() {
```

is highlighted not the line "debugger;"
Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: `ExecuteScriptAsync` is just an extension method, the actual call has some default values, one being `lineNumber`, which defaults to `0`, so my guess is that's the problem. Probably should be `1`. See
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L245
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/IFrame.cs#L106
If you have a chance to test, please let me know and we can see about fixing in the next release.

Comment: @amaitland thanks for the response. I have moved on to embedding the code into a HTML template which gives me a host of unintended benefits so I'll be sticking with that approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by embedding the code into a HTML text file, and then navigating to the text file. Now the correct line is highlighted.